# could not open a nodejs project in intellij phpstorm and idea

Tags: node.js, express, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Although I have installed the nodejs plugin in phpstorm IDE I cannot separately open a nodejs project.But I can open an empty project and run nodejs codes in there.
The main reason is to have the separate folder structure for nodejs project(specially when creating a **nodejs express** project).

Additionally, I cannot install the nodejs plugin in the IDEA too.

I have gone through their documentation but I couldn't find a solution to this.
Please help me with this.

**Note:**
Phpstorm version - 8.01
IDEA version - 2016.2.04

Comment: The NodeJS plugin does not work with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (because it doesn't include the JS plugin). What edition of IDEA are you using?

Comment: @Bastien: it's IDEA community version 2016.2.4.but according to the tutorial series of newboston [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WH5qsGnFkBM&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_&index=16) IDEA can open seperate nodejs projects.Please help me with this

Comment: Unfortunately it only works in IDEA Ultimate, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/running-and-debugging-node-js.html

Comment: @bastein : yes,i got to know it too.but don't know the reason why it is not working in  phpstorm.

Comment: @bastein: went for  webstorm,it is giving the capability to do seperate  nodejs projects.thnks for the help...